# Problem: Can't change the other html page when the textarea is filled

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my html:

```
<div class="secondcontent">
<div>
<form>
    <label>Do you have any experince with animal care and handling?</label> <br>
    <textarea id="textarea" type="text" class="size" name="experinces" rows="50" cols="80" 
    placeholder="Do you have any experience in caring for cats, dogs, birds, rodents, reptiles and other animals? Do you have/had any pets? If so, for how long? What are your experiences with animals? What do you wish to accomplish with us? etc."
    style="margin:0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    </textarea> 
</form>
</div>
<br>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button class="button"><a href="50_form.html">BACK</a></button>
<button class="button" type="submit" class="button" style="margin-left:5px;">NEXT</button>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('textarea[type="text"]').forEach(b => {
    b.addEventListener('focusout', setInputBackground)
});

function setInputBackground() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = !!this.value ? "white" : "rgb(255,221,221)";
}

function emptyField(){
    if (this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,221,221)"){
        return false;
    }
    if (this.style.backgroundColor = "white"){
        return true;
    }
}

form.addEventListener("submit",(b)=>{

    if(document.getElementById("textarea").value == '') {
        demo.style.color = "red";
        demo.innerText = "You must fill up the fields in red.";
        b.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
        location.replace("100_form.html");
        b.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

The problem is when I put some text in the textarea it doesn't send me to the other html page and it doesn't output the message when you leave the textarea empty.

Comment: How do you set the `form` variable?

Comment: Also, where is the ```demo``` variable being declared?

Comment: the declaration for demo is 
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
but i dont understand setting the form?